# Oracle Dependency (notification) , how invasive?

Tags: c#, oracle, notifications, odp.net

I am planning to use Oracle dependency notification(ODP.Net) in a production environment to update several tables cached in on a SQL Server.

My understanding is that this is not invasive in oracle database, I assume Oracle simply broadcast commits on subscribed tables and does not bother to guarantee that notifications are received by the consumers; therefore I assume it does not hold any server resource.

Although I have tested this in test environment where CRUD operations are minimal, but in real live environment CRUDS are much more frequent. 
Will Dependency notifications hold server resources until all pending notifications are serviced by the client ?.